# Which tool can best extrude two angles from the same face?

Tags: modeling, modifiers, extrude

I've been teaching myself to model for a few months now, and recently a friend asked me if I would be able to create this hair pin for her. At first I thought I thought I could make a simple moon shape, make a loop cut down the center and extrude it up from the center. However, the model I need to create has two extruded edges on the same face and this is where I'm at a complete loss of what tool can help me accomplish my goal.

This is the shape I'm trying to achieve
[image: Goal]

This is what I've tried so far[image: subdivided]

This was after adding two more cuts and edge sliding to give a sharper angle.[image: loop cut and edge slide]

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 3):

Use your image as a background image. You could begin with the ridges of your two half-moons, then expand, connect the vertices, move up the faces, etc...

[image]